# How to count number of screens via powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I wanted to count the number of screens detected via powershell/cmd.

got the below to work but I wanted to count the number of screens detected as numeric.

```
@for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=: " %i IN (`powershell.exe Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams ^| findstr /r /C:"Active"`) do @echo %i
```

this returns the below suppose I have 2 screens connected. Would anyone help me change the output to the number of screens active instead which is true to numeric/or count the number of true? i.e  = 2

```
True 
True
```

Comment: Do you want to use Powershell, or do you want to use a batch file? Choose one.

Comment: @DanielMann powershell

Comment: `powershell.exe … | findstr /C:"Active" | find /C /V ""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the solution, you're just mixing a batch syntax with PowerShell for no reason.

`@(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams).Length` is a pure PowerShell solution.

If you want to filter it to only active displays, then `@(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams | where-object { $_.Active }).Length`.

Comment: since the OP wants a _count_, would it be a better fit to use the `.Count` property? you are already forcing the CIM call to give an array ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the rep to add a comment directly to @Daemon-5 but I found his code not to work for me as it only reported one monitor connected when I in actual fact have 2 (connected via a dock).

This is what I am using:
`for /F %%M in ('wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "Service='monitor' and Status='OK'" get DeviceID /VALUE ^| find /C "="') do (set monitors=%%M)`

You can then simply `echo %monitors%`

Answer (score 0):

Use internal utilities if you plan to use batch-file only.

```
FOR /F "delims=:" %%a in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi  path WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams  get Active ^|findstr /n "Active"') DO @echo %%a
```

P.S.
But rememeber `wmic.exe` has no longer [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features).